# GL_SCISSOR_TEST not working

Tags: opengl, go, glfw

I'm using bindings of [OpenGL](http://godoc.org/github.com/go-gl/gl) and [glfw](http://godoc.org/github.com/go-gl/glfw) for Go on OS X 10.7, OpenGL version 3.x.

I enable `GL_SCISSOR_TEST` and set scissor rectangle to `(0, 0, 1, 1)`. But it has absolutely no effect on the rendering -- the whole viewport is being updated.

Here's the code:

```
gl.Enable(gl.SCISSOR_TEST)
gl.Scissor(0, 0, 1, 1)
fmt.Printf("scissor enabled = %v\n", gl.IsEnabled(gl.SCISSOR_TEST))
box := make([]int32, 4)
gl.GetIntegerv(gl.SCISSOR_BOX, box)
fmt.Printf("scissor box = %v\n", box)
```

Console output:

```
scissor enabled = true
scissor box = [0 0 1 1]
```

I'm not sure what to make of this. The fact that `glIsEnabled()` and `glGetIntegerv()` both report correct values make me think that there is still some state missing that is necessary for activating the scissor test. I tried enabling `GL_STENCIL_TEST` and initializing `glfw` with 1 and 8 bits for stencil, still no effect, although `glIsEnabled(GL_STENCIL_TEST)` returns `true`.

Comment: That's not "the code". That is a *fragment* of "the code". I don't see where you're actually rendering anything in this code. And the scissor box doesn't do anything unless you render with it active.

Comment: @NicolBolas Like I said, when I render, the whole viewport gets updated instead of one pixel in the lower left corner.

Comment: Saying that doesn't mean your code is doing it correctly. There is nothing wrong with the code you're showing. Therefore, either there's a bug between you and the GPU, or there is a bug in your code *outside* of what you've shown.